# Print Column contents, according to particular contents of another column

Tags: pandas, filter

I have a DataFrame with columns like trip_id, service_id etc., like

```
trip_id     service_id
1            weekday
2            weekday
3            weekday
4            saturday
5            saturday
6            holiday
7            sunday
```

I want to print out the trip_id's for all 'weekday', for all saturdays and holidays, separately. I tried with the

```
join_df.query(join_df['service_id'] == 'weekday')
```

way, but it doesn't seem to be the right one. I also tried

```
print join_df[join_df.service_id =='weekdays']
```

didnt work. Got an empty dataframe as the output.

Could anybody help me with this please.
Thank you

Comment: please provide an example of your DataFrame and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typo (it's weekday not weekdays), either the latter or using loc should work:

```
In [11]: df[df.service_id == 'weekday']
Out[11]:
   trip_id service_id
0        1    weekday
1        2    weekday
2        3    weekday

In [12]: df.loc[df.service_id == 'weekday']
Out[12]:
   trip_id service_id
0        1    weekday
1        2    weekday
2        3    weekday
```

You can also use query, but your syntax isn't quite correct:

```
In [13]: df.query("service_id == 'weekday'")
Out[13]:
   trip_id service_id
0        1    weekday
1        2    weekday
2        3    weekday
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following DataFrame:

```
       service_id
trip_id           
1          weekday
2          weekday
3          weekday
4         saturday
5         saturday
6          holiday
7           sunday
```

Then you can loop through all the unique values in the `service_id` column and print out a subset of your original DataFrame using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).  For example:

```
for grp in df['service_id'].unique():
    print df[df['service_id'] == grp]
```

Output:

```
        service_id
trip_id           
1          weekday
2          weekday
3          weekday
```

---

```
        service_id
trip_id           
4         saturday
5         saturday
```

---

```
        service_id
trip_id           
6          holiday
```

---

```
        service_id
trip_id           
7           sunday
```